# half circle on y axis with text svg

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to draw half circle on y axis without ruining my text

```html
    <svg
      height="300px"
      width="300px"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        id="txt"
        fill="blue"
        d="M20 50 A10 10,0, 0 0 , 100 50"
        transform="rotate(90, 50 50)"
      ></path>
      <text>
        <textPath href="#txt">perpare your self</textPath>
      </text>
    </svg>
```

when I rotate the circle the text looks messy

I want it like this
[image]

Comment: Define messy. What do you want it to look like?

Comment: I want it readable  and I add image to what I want it look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ive rewritten the d attribute of the path. Now it's the same path you have but reversed.
2. The text have `dominant-baseline="hanging"` so that it falls inside the circle.
3. I've also added `textLength="125"` to match the length of the path. For longer strings you may need to change the font size. In order to know the length of the path you can use `path.getTotalLength()`

```js
console.log(txt.getTotalLength())
```

```html
<svg
      height="300px"
      width="300px"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        id="txt"
        fill="lightblue"   
        d="M100,50A10 10 0 0 1 20,50"
        transform="rotate(90, 50 50)"
      ></path>
      <text dominant-baseline="hanging" textLength="125">
        <textPath href="#txt">perpare your self</textPath>
      </text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Was also typing an answer. Minor addition, no transform needed with a ``m50 0a10 10 0 000 100`` path

Comment: hey @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Feel free to add your answer.

Comment: nah, you need them points ;-)